# nlme beginner question

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I am trying to fit a mixed model to my data using the nlme library in R.

Here's what I have:

```
df <- data.frame(phen = phen.info.box[,2], hap = as.factor(mouse.haps), strain = as.factor(mouse.strains))

fit <- nlme(model = phen ~ hap + (1|strain),
            data = df, 
            fixed = hap ~ 1,
            random = strain ~ 1,
            start = rep(1, 832),
            correlation = K)
```

And the error I get is:

```
Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, eval(parse(text = paste("~1", deparse(groups[[2]]), :
invalid formula for groups
```

I would like to do more complex things down the road, but I'm having trouble just getting this basic model running.  I have read through the nlme documentation and can't seem to figure out this "invalid formula" error.  I got the same error with the line "random = strain ~ 1" omitted.  I read in the documentation that simply putting "fixed = var ~ 1" signals a single fixed effect, which is what I want.

I have to use nlme instead of lme4 because, as far as I understand, lme4 won't let me specify a variance-covariance matrix on the random effects and that's important to me (see "correlation = K" line.)

OK, I'm getting downvotes for this and I'm not sure why.  I assume it's people thinking "this question is too easy to even be asked -- the asker must not have tried to solve it at all!".  I have been looking through documentation and examples online and I cannot, for the life of me see the difference between how I'm doing it and this example I found online:

```
nlme.fit <- nlme(lgcopy ~ logexp2(p1,b1,p2,b2,day),
             fixed = p1+b1+p2+b2 ~1,random = p1+b1+p2+b2 ~1, 
             data =aids.dat,start=c(start))
```

which apparently works.

Comment: Isn't `(1|strain)` only used in lmer (from package lme4) formulas, but not in nlme (from package nlme) formulas? What happens if you remove that part from the current formula?

Comment: I removed the (1|strain) and replaced it with just strain. Good catch, but same error persists.

Comment: Can you post your data, `dput(df)`, so we can run the code?  There may be a problem with your formula `phen ~ hap + (1|strain)` or as you say you modified it to `phen ~ hap + strain`.  As the help for `nlme` states it is looking for a **nonlinear model formula** and it looks like you are providing it with a linear forumula (where the coefficients are assumed rather than specified).

Comment: Jean, great idea.  I've now switched to using "lme" and am playing with that.

Comment: dput was too long, even for df[1:3,], so here's str:     'data.frame': 832 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ phen  : num  81.8 73.8 80.5 86 81.3 ...
 $ hap   : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ strain: Factor w/ 45 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 ...

Comment: @JeanV.Adams, post an answer and i'll accept it.  I just got it working with lme.